# What is the Facebook Graph API query for this link to a photo?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm having good luck using python and the FB graph api to collect reactions, comments from Facebook posts however, I'm having trouble targeting this specific photo link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/SheShopped/photos/a.432191143458704.110954.428340903843728/1367643623246780/?type=3&theater
```

Can anyone tell me how to deconstruct this link into a FB graph query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look at the comments of this specific photo you just need to extract the id from the link (it's the last segment of the url) which is `1367643623246780`. You'll find the comments at `1367643623246780/comments`:

[image: Example Output]

If you want to find this picture and others like it, you need to notice the type of picture (it is a 'Timeline Photo'). Looking at the relevant API-Documentation ([Open Graph Page Photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/)) these can be found at 'SheShopped/photos/uploaded':

[image: Example Output]